# Clean and easy way to add meta tags to my D7 website

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I'm looking for a easy way to add meta tags to my D7 website. Not that I'm afraid of code or anything like it, but the content managers (Marketing => biggest IT noobs you've ever seen) want to add meta-tags by using the Drupal UI.

I've checked the [MetaTags Quick](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick)-module, but it seems like this module is only capable of adding path-meta tags. Are there any alternatives? Or what is the most clean way to add meta tags do my Drupal 7 website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drupal 7 the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module is the way to go:

> The Meta tags module allows you to automatically provide structured metadata about your website.

MetaTags Quick is also good, but Meta tags has more features.

Comment: Thanks. I just stumbled upon `Simple meta`. I assume you find `Meta tags` more suitable for the job?

Comment: I haven't used "Simple meta" to be honest, but I've had no problems with "Meta tags" and I find it very comprehensive. As a side note, "MetaTags Quick" was originally developed as a stop-gap solution to the meta tag issue for Drupal 7, while "Nodewords" was ported over to "Meta tags". It's since become a good module in its own right, but I personally prefer "Meta tags"

Comment: In "Simple Meta" it's possible to add a title, description and keywords manually. Is this a feature in "Meta tags" as well? Because I don't find it right away...

Comment: I'm not sure really I've never needed to do that. It does provide some hooks which might help, have a look in the metatag.metatag.inc file included with the module

Comment: your module is great! It does exactly what I expected. But there seems to be a nasty bug somewhere... Could you take a look at this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30509/meta-tags-arent-saved-with-all-content-types? Thanks in advance!