# Meta tags aren't saved with all content types

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I use the module [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) for adding meta data to my nodes. And it works like a charm. It's super easy to add meta tages like `title`, `keywords`, `description`,... even our IT-noob marketing team can do so. It's awesome.

However, not all content types seems to be able to save those meta data. I've got 12 content types and 3 of them don't display the meta data. Although I add them like on the other nodes...

Here is the source code of a node without any meta:

[image]

And here with meta:

[image]

So correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any meta data in the first example.

Strange part, all the data is present in the database (table `metatag`), so all nodes does save the meta data, but for some reason, some content types aren't displaying the meta data.

What could be the cause of this "bug". Could it be something like hiding certain content in the template files since they all have a separate `.tpl.php` file? Or what other causes are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1310780) with the module.

Try the following code in node.tpl.php.

```
render($content['metatags']);
```

Alternatively, try with the following code in page.tpl.php.

```
print render($page['content']['metatags']);
```

Comment: Ok, great! This helped me a lot! Thanks a million!!