# Meta tag page descriptions

Tags: 7, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta tags aren't saved with all content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30509/meta-tags-arent-saved-with-all-content-types)

I'm using [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) to control the meta data on my Drupal 7 site.  This module seems to give your nodes control over what your page descriptions display via the vertical menu at the bottom of the page you're editing.  This description doesn't show though.

The only thing I can think of is the global options which you can find by "configuring" the module itself.  If I set a global page description, it will show on all pages, and if I disable it, or leave it blank, there will be no description shown.

Why is the data set on individual nodes not overwriting this global quality?  There doesn't seem to be another module to help me with descriptions either.

Comment: What @googletorp said. I'm using Meta Tags in plenty of projects and have never had an issue like that...sounds like the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this module successfully today actually - with no configuration alterations.

One reason for things not working for you could be your theme which after all does control the markup for your site.

Comment: I'm using the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) html5 theme as the base and I'm not using any template suggestions for the main page layout.  Thank you for narrowing it down.  I'll go see if the omega guys have anymore insight.

Comment: Ok I figured it out!  Whew!  I'm using Display Suite as well, and after you add the Meta Tags module, a "Meta Tag" field becomes available in the node display setup (Edit->Manage Display->Full Content).  All I had to do was pull that field up to a visible area.  Super unintuitive, but I'm so glad it's working now.